# Cannot understand the conclusion of the proof that $\lim_\limits{x \to \infty} ( 1 + \frac{1}{x})^{x} = e$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-explanation

I'm struggling to understand an unusual proof that $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)^{x} = e$

Note: before starting this proof we know already the following limit for $a_{n}$ $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n} = e$.

The way the proof proceeds is the following: "we know that $a_{n}$ is a growing sequence that goes to $e$, therefore for each $\epsilon > 0 $, there is a $v$ (which we can assume to be bigger than $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$) such that for each $n > v$ we have":

$e - \epsilon < \left( 1 + \dfrac{1}{n} ​\right)^{n} < e$

Here I understand that this comes from the fact that:
$ \left| \left(1+\dfrac{1}{n} \right)^{n} - e  \right| < \epsilon$ and the member on the the RHS ($e$) comes from the fact that $\epsilon + e > \epsilon$ but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Now, assuming that $x > v+1$ and $[x]$ being the integer part of $x$, we have $[x] > v$ and the author proceeds to squeeze $\left( 1 + \dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{x}$ as follows

$\left( 1 + \dfrac{1}{[x] + 1}\right)^{[x]} < \left(1 + \dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{x} < \left( 1 + \dfrac{1}{[x]}\right)^{[x]+1}$

Then there are some additional steps here that I can follow without problems (I can add them if needed), at the end the author ends up with:

$e - (1+e)\epsilon \leq \left( 1 + \dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{x} \leq e + e\epsilon$

and concludes by saying that this proves the original statement that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^{x} = e$.

This is the part that I do not understand, I could have understood that if it were $e-\epsilon$ on the left side and $e+\epsilon$ on the right side, that will fit the definition of the limit; is there any reason why a multiple of $\epsilon$ will continue to fit the definition? I spent hours for the past two days looking for an explanation of that or a similar proof and I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon'=(1+e)\varepsilon$.  Note that $\varepsilon'>0$ can be arbitrarily small.

Then, for any $\varepsilon'>0$ there exists a number $v+1>0$ such that whenever $x>v+1$ we have

$$\left|\left(1+\frac1x\right)^{x}-e\right|<\varepsilon'$$

Comment: but what about the RHS then? shouldn't that be $e + (1+e)\epsilon$? I understand that $(1+e)\epsilon > e\epsilon$ therefore the inequality chain makes sense. Is that what the proof is implying? At the same time the fact that $\left( 1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x} \leq e + (1+e)\epsilon$ is not proved by the conclusion; is that relevant?

Comment: For the right-hand side, clearly $e+e\epsilon<e+(1+e)\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the general result that if $a_n,b_n$ converge to limits $a,b$ in $\Bbb R$ then $a_nb_n\to ab.$

For $x\ge 1$ we have $$(1+1/(1+[x]))^{-1}\cdot(1+1/(1+[x]) )^{1+[x]} =$$ $$=(1+1/(1+[x]) )^{[x]} \le$$ $$\le (1+1/x)^x\le$$ $$\le  (1+1/[x])^{1+[x]}=$$ $$=(1+1/[x])^{[x]}\cdot (1+1/[x]).$$

The top displayed line converges to $1\cdot e=e$ and the bottom displayed line converges to $e\cdot 1=e.$

Answer (score 0):

Note $−(1+)\varepsilon\leqslant(1+1/)^\leqslant +\varepsilon $ is true for every $\varepsilon$, so if we take limit $\varepsilon$ tends to 0, then left most side and right most side both are going to e. So by Sandwich theorem,
$ e\leqslant(1+1/)^\leqslant $ for all x. Now taking the limit as x goes to infinity you get the result.