# Implications of a sequence having a limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-explanation

While re-reading a proof, which I now understand thanks to ([Cannot understand the conclusion of the proof that $\lim_\limits{x \to \infty} ( 1 + \frac{1}{x})^{x} = e$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4199318/cannot-understand-the-conclusion-of-the-proof-that-lim-limitsx-to-infty/4199562#4199562)), I realized that I cannot accept one of the assumption of the proof, that is the following section:

"If the sequence $a_{n} = \left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}$ is increasing and tends to $e$, then for each $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $v$ (which we can assume to be bigger than $\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$), such that for each $n>v$ we have:

$e-\varepsilon < \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n} < e$

My understanding is the following: if that sequence has $e$ as limit, then:

$\left| \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n} -e \right| < \varepsilon$

$\iff$

$-\varepsilon < \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n} - e < \varepsilon$

$\iff$
(adding $e$ to all parts)

$e-\varepsilon < \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n} < e+\varepsilon$

Having said that, I cannot get how the author assumes the right part of the inquality, i.e.:
$\left( 1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n} < e$.

In my mind $e+\varepsilon > e$ and therefore:

$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n} < e+\varepsilon \nless e$

Is there anything that I am missing here?

Comment: “If the sequence is **increasing** and tends to $e$”...

Comment: Also you can expand $a_n$ using binomial theorem and show that $a_n  < e$

Comment: OK I believe I get that at this point, obviously $a_{n}$ is always less than $e$ as $n \to \infty$, I was stuck with the inequality and apparently I did not immediately translate that part of the sentence into an additional inequality

Comment: @HansLundmark if you can repost that statement as an answer to the question, I will be able to close the question, thanks!

Comment: Questions such as this are usually never closed.  If someone were to post an answer, and if you then *accepted* the answer, that would signify that the issue has been resolved.  However, it doesn't really matter for this particular question, because anyone glancing at the comments will immediately recognize that the question has been resolved.

Comment: An exception re previous comment is that if reviewers determine that your question is a duplicate of a previously asked question, then the reviewers will vote to close the question.  If there are then 5 votes-to-close, the question will be closed and you will receive an explanation.  However, no action is required on your part.

Answer (score 1):

Given that $a_n$ is increasing and converges to $e$, we can show that $a_n < e$. Suppose there exist a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_k >e$. This implies that $\forall n \ge k$ we have $a_n > e$ since $a_n > a_k$. This implies that $\lim a_n = e > e$ by using [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Properties) of limits which is a contradiction.

Alternatively observe that for $r \le n,$ $$ {n \choose r} \frac 1 {n^r} =  \frac{n (n-1) \cdots (n-r+1)}{r! n^r} = \frac{1}{r!} (1 - \frac 1n)\cdots (1 - \frac {r-1}{n}) < \frac 1 {r!}$$ So using binomial theorem, $$( 1 + 1/n )^ {n} = \sum_{r=0}^{n} {n \choose r} \frac 1 {n^r} < \sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac 1 {r!} < e$$.